# The probability that k fixed elements of the set belong to one cycles in random permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given the set of n elements: $\mathbb{A} = \{1,...,n\}$.
Fix $k$ elements in the set. And consider a random permutation $\pi : \mathbb{A} \rightarrow \mathbb{A}$.

So any permutation can be represented by the product of cycles.

How to determine the probability that all k fixed elements of the set $\mathbb{A}$ are in one cycle.

My result is :
$$ \frac{\sum_{i = 0}^{n - k} {{k+i} \brack {1}} \binom{n-k-i+1}{i}(n - k - i)!}{n!} $$

where ${a \brack b}$ - a Stirling number of the first kind

Comment: Indeed I've got following probability:
$ \frac{\sum_{i = 0}^{n - k} {{k+i} \brack {1}} (n - k - i)!}{n!}$,
where ${a \brack b}$ - Stirling number of the first kind.

Comment: I mean I tried to solve the problem and got the result.

Comment: Best to transfer your comment into your question so that people see it.

Comment: I am not sure my result is true.

Comment: The probability is $\frac1k$, but I don't yet see a proof whose simplicity matches that of the result.

Comment: Solving the problem I fix first k elements and consider all permutation which have a cycle including these k elements.

$\pi_1 = (1,..,k) *$ (all permutation of remaining n - k elements) , i.e. I fixed cycle.

$\pi_2 =  (1,..,k,k+1) * $(all permutation of remaining n - k - 1 elements), i.e. I fixed cycle again

and so on

Comment: Hmm. Now I think result is:

$\frac{\sum_{i = 0}^{n - k} {{k+i} \brack {1}} \binom{n-k-i + 1}{i} (n - k - i)!}{n!}$

Answer (score 2):

Start with some element $a$ of the $k$ elements and then in each step map the current element to an element selected uniformly at random from the elements not yet selected. The probability that all $k$ elements are in the same cycle is the probability that this process selects $a$ as the last of $k$ elements. Since all $k$ elements are equally likely to be selected last, the probability is $\frac1k$.

---

*Edit:* Since you seem to also be interested in a proof that sums over the cycle lengths, here's how I originally arrived at the $\frac1k$ result: There can be $m$ additional elements in the cycle together with the $k$ elements, with $0\le m\le n-k$. There are $(m+k-1)!$ different cycles containing the $m+k$ elements, and $(n-m-k)!$ different ways to permute the remaining elements. Thus the desired probability is

\begin{align}
\frac1{n!}\sum_{m=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-k}m(m+k-1)!(n-m-k)!
&=\sum_{m=0}^{n-k}\frac{(n-k)!(m+k-1)!}{n!m!}\\
&=\frac1k\frac1{\binom nk}\sum_{m=0}^{n-k}\binom{m+k-1}m\\
&=\frac1k\;,
\end{align}

where the last step uses the [Christmas stocking theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChristmasStockingTheorem.html) (also known as the hockey stick identity).

Comment: I cannot understand why it is true:
The probability that all $k$ elements are in the same cycle is the probability that this process selects $a$ as the last of $k$ elements.

Comment: Let $\pi$ - random permutation. We fix element $a$ of the $k$ elements and map it, result: $\pi(a)$. We require that $\pi(a) \neq a$. So the probability that $\pi(a) \neq a$ is $\frac{n-1}{n}.$ Next step take $\pi(a)$ and map it. We require again $\pi(\pi(a)) \neq a$. So such probability equals $ \frac{n-2}{n-1} $. And so on. 
Go to $\pi^k(a)$. And now we require $\pi^k(a) = a$. Such probability is $\frac{n - k}{n - k - 1}$ . 

Right?

Comment: @J.Exactor: No. You're requiring that $a$ be in a cycle of $k$ elements. It can be in a cycle of any number of elements. You should disregard all other elements and focus only on the $k$ elements. Each of these is equally likely to be the last one selected, and the cycle contains all $k$ elements if and only if $a$ is selected last. If you want to spell it out, you get the same chain of fractions as you wrote above, but with $k$ instead of $n$, and their product telescopes to $\frac1k$.

Comment: I see my mistake. I checked the result on sets of 3,4,5 elements and it works. But I don't see why I can disregard all other elements.

Comment: If reformulate the problem we have following:

There are n people. We enumerate them, choose k people and put them at round table. For another people consider all permutation. It is the case when only k people form required cycle.

Next we choose one man from $n - k$ people and put him to our $k$ people. We get the cycle of $(k+1)$ people with our $k$ people. For another $(n - k - 1)$ people consider all permutation. And so on.

I know it is complicated to solve such way. But I understand how form answer. In the answer above I cannot understand why we disregard another elements.

Comment: On this site: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation_statistics
I find out that $Pr[$there is a cycle of length $k] = \frac1k$. Is it linked with the result of the problem?

Comment: @J.Exactor: It may well be linked -- I had the same thought, since it's a similar nice and simple result, but I couldn't find a connection. About your calculation: Yes, I originally solved it by summing over all possible cycle lengths -- that's when I wrote the comment under the question that the answer is $\frac1k$ but I hadn't found a correspondingly simple proof yet. About disregarding the other elements: It doesn't matter how many other elements you select in between -- the symmetry among the $k$ elements ensures that each of them is selected as the last of them with equal probability.

Comment: @J.Exactor: I added the "pedestrian" proof to the answer.